# Bar Chart and Stacked Bar Chart using similar data on one page

Tags: eclipse, charts, javafx-8, bar-chart

I am trying to show some data in a bar chart and stacked bar chart using JavaFx. I am using 4 series into which I populate the data, using eclipse oxygen.

I use series1 and series2 in the Bar Chart.
I use series1, series2, series3, and series4 in the Stacked Bar Chart.

I have created my screen using the JavaFx Scene Builder. Populate the scenes and displaying the data. My problem is that I am not able to show both the graphs at the same time. Only the latter gets populated, depending on the order of the population. The extra bit I have added is that the graphs expand on a mouse enter event and then reduces to the orginal size on the mouse exit event.

Can anyone help me by pointing out what I am doing wrong? 
My code is as follows

```
@FXML
private void bcsbg_mouseentered() {
    if (!clickEntered) {
        clickEntered = true;
        prefWidth = bcByGroup.getPrefWidth();
        prefHeight = bcByGroup.getPrefHeight();
        bcByGroup.setPrefSize(1500, 900);
        gXAxis.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        gXAxis.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        gYAxis.setPrefHeight(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        gYAxis.setPrefWidth(Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
        gXAxis.setVisible(true);
        gYAxis.setVisible(true);
        gXAxis.setLabel("Value");  
        gYAxis.setLabel("Question"); 
        gXAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        gYAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(true);
        gXAxis.setTickMarkVisible(true);
        gYAxis.setTickMarkVisible(true);

        sbcByAll.setVisible(false);

    } else {
        clickEntered = false;
        bcByGroup.setPrefSize(prefWidth, prefHeight);
        gXAxis.setPrefHeight(0);
        gXAxis.setPrefWidth(0);
        gYAxis.setPrefHeight(0);
        gYAxis.setPrefWidth(0);
        gXAxis.setVisible(false);
        gYAxis.setVisible(false);
        gXAxis.setLabel("");  
        gYAxis.setLabel("");
        gXAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        gYAxis.setTickLabelsVisible(false);
        gXAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);
        gYAxis.setTickMarkVisible(false);

        sbcByAll.setVisible(true);
        sbcByAll.getData().clear();
        sbcByAll.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3, series4);

    }

    bcByGroup.getData().clear();
    bcByGroup.getData().addAll(series1, series2);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is not in your code, but in the way the chart API is written. (I'm not normally a fan of criticizing languages or standard libraries, but parts of this API appear to have been written by an unsupervised intern with a particularly bad hangover.)

The `XYChart.Data` class keeps a [reference to the node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) that displays the data. (This fairly obviously violates the most basic tenets of MVC, and makes separating the data into a different class completely redundant.)

Consequently, if you try to use the same data in two charts, the same node tries to appear in two parents, which is not allowed, and you only see the visualization of the data in one place. Unfortunately, you need to replicate the data for each chart.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Dave. You are right. I did not go through the standard documentation on the XYData.Chart to notice that this object would be attached to the node in which the data was going to be displayed.

I was really hoping to avoid replication but the code does work as soon as the data series is replicated and attached to the different charts.

As mentioned by Dave,

> The XYChart.Data class keeps a [reference to the node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/chart/XYChart.Data.html#nodeProperty) that displays the data. (This fairly obviously violates the most basic tenets of MVC, and makes separating the data into a different class completely redundant.)

Please go through the standard documentation provided in Dave's link.